# Ruby on rails Kubernetes deployment in Google Cloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

Here is my kubernetes service desription look like on Google Cloud Platform:

## `kubectl describe service sso`

```
Name:                   sso
Namespace:              default
Labels:                 app=sso
Selector:               app=sso
Type:                   LoadBalancer
IP:                     10.39.254.125
LoadBalancer Ingress:   35.184.96.95
Port:                   <unset> 80/TCP
NodePort:               <unset> 31260/TCP
Endpoints:              10.36.1.12:8080,10.36.1.13:8080,10.36.2.8:8080
Session Affinity:       None
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubObjectPath   Type            Reason                  Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------   --------        ------                  -------
  8m            8m              1       {service-controller }                   Normal          CreatingLoadBalancer    Creating load balancer
  7m            7m              1       {service-controller }                   Normal          CreatedLoadBalancer     Created load balancer
```

## `kubectl get pods`

```
NAME                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sso-868819325-8g8g7   1/1       Running   0          14m
sso-868819325-sbtz7   1/1       Running   0          14m
sso-868819325-zd3vk   1/1       Running   0          14m
```

Isn't it on ip `35.184.96.95` my rails application will be available?
I couldn't found any error. But on `35.184.96.95` nothing shows up.

Please help!

## Updated

## `kt get services`

```
NAME         CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   10.39.240.1    <none>           443/TCP        6h
sso          10.39.245.40   104.154.62.129   80:30816/TCP   36m
```

Comment: What happens when you run `kt get services`?

Comment: like this 
`NAME         CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   10.39.240.1    <none>           443/TCP        6h
sso          10.39.245.40   104.154.62.129   80:30816/TCP   36m
`

Comment: Weird. Your app should be available through this external IP.

Comment: is it some kind of firewall issue? @Bonifacio2